# Groovy Split String with possible String

Tags: java, arrays, groovy, split

I am using groovy to parse a in a file which needs to be split into an array using groovy.

The problem is that the used delimiter "," is in the one field so a the split command is not correctly applied. The output will use a different delimiter (e.g. "|")

```
ELEMENT 1-01,"X0185-CX2F-01-PW(SATop,20211,10.42.81.0)",2020-02-18 09:00:00,15,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0,0,0
```

Does the groovy `split(",") function` consider the field as a single string literal?

Comment: Of course--if you want to parse CSV use a CSV parser (or roll your own).

Comment: CSV parser (which is what you help) can't be implemented by simple `split(",")`, precisely for reasons you've just outlined.

Answer (score 0):

As so often, a regexp or a split will work at first glance, and then
horribly fail once data show its real face.  So as many data formats a
proper parser is usually safe route and this is also true for CSV.

[Pick one you like](https://github.com/osiegmar/FastCSV) and then it's
usually just little bit experimenting and you are good to go.  E.g.

```
@Grab(group='de.siegmar', module='fastcsv', version='1.0.3')
import de.siegmar.fastcsv.reader.*

def data = '''ELEMENT 1-01,"X0185-CX2F-01-PW(SATop,20211,10.42.81.0)",2020-02-18 09:00:00,15,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0,0,0'''
def csvReader = new CsvReader()
try (def csvParser = csvReader.parse(new java.io.StringReader(data))) {
    def row = csvParser.nextRow()
    assert row.getField(1)=='X0185-CX2F-01-PW(SATop,20211,10.42.81.0)'
}
```

If you are not convinced, think about the next problems you will face:

- line breaks
- `"` inside quoted cells